# Parse double with specific decimal symbol

Tags: java

How can I set a specific decimal separator for a double? The next method should parse the string version of a double only if the separator is the given value, but works for both, DOT or COMMA. I want it to return true only if the string has the given separator.

```java
public static boolean isValid(char decimalSeparator) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(decimalSeparator);
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

    try {
        df.parse("22,22").doubleValue();
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite possible that the locale you use uses `,` as the grouping separator (en_US does). So "," will be tolerated, it just won't be interpreted as a decimal separator. What are you trying to verify with that method? You parse a hard-coded string value and ignore the result, that seems weird.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. But I want to parse la value only if the decimal separator is the given parameter. Is it posible? So, it should be more strict.

Comment: I'm still unclear what your goal is. So if you pass in `.` is `123` a valid value? Is `123,456` a valid value? And why?

Comment: are you saying that it currently parses `10.01` and `10,01` as the same value? because it the comma is not the decimal point, `10,01` should be parsed as `1001.00`

Comment: Is not the same value, one is 22,22 and the other one is 22.0. But this method is just a validation, so I want to throw exception if the method returned the wrong value (22.0). I use this method in GUI to validate if the user used the right decimal separator in an input box. (decimal/comma). So, the website will establish the decimal separator, regardless the locale from the user OS.

Comment: Couldn't you just check if the value as a string contains the seperator?

Comment: I want to validate if it is double, so it should also check if the input contains any letters and to fail in case of it contains any. Basically all that I want is to do a validate for a double ( Ex: Double.parse("22.22")) but I want to use my decimal separator.

Comment: @JohnR.: what I keep trying to tell you is that "22,22" *is* a valid double, even with `.` as a decimal separator. If all you want to do is "parse a double with a given decimal separator" then that should be parsed (as 2222).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) for `parse(String)` says

> "Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string.**"

When you provide a string with the "wrong" decimal separator, this parse method will stop when it gets to this character, and (probably) return a `Long` value rather than a `Double` value.  A `ParseException` is *only* thrown if the first unexpected character is the first character of the string.

The solution is to use the two argument `parse` method ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition))):

```
    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    String str = "22,22";
    df.parse(str, pp);
    return pp.getIndex() == str.length() && pp.getErrorIndex() == -1;
```

Note that this overload of `parse` does not throw `ParseException`

Comment: It return true regardless the given parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    isValid("22,22", ",");
    isValid("22.22", ".");
    isValid("2222", ",");
    isValid("2222", ".");
    isValid(",22", ",");
    isValid("22,", ",");
    isValid("22,22", ".");



}

static boolean isValid(String number, String ds) {
    ds = ds.replace(".", "\\.");
    String[] parts = number.split(ds);

    try {
        switch (parts.length) {
            case 0: Integer.parseInt(number); break;
            case 1: Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); break;
            case 2: Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); break;
            default: throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
        return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    } 


}
```

you may add extra conditions, like check the decimal-separator's length if it has only one char, or if ",22" can be "0,22"